# Confused by how to pass correctly props to descendant components

Tags: reactjs

I have a question. Example I have 4 components and A includes B, B includes C and C includes D.
I have a state `{ mode: 'dashboard'  }` and function `changeMode(mode) => { this.setState({mode: mode})}` in A. Without Context or Redux,
i want to use the function in D.

1.So should i pass the function like:

```
<B changeMode={this.changeMode} />
and in B will be <C changeMode={this.props.changeMode} />
```

and so on.

2.Or will like: `<B changeMode={this.changeMode} />`
and in B we will declare a function: `changeMode = (mode) => {this.props.changeMode(mode)}` and so on.
What is the better way and why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first option is right

Comment: There is always React Hooks :)

Comment: @DominikTargosz can you tell me why is the second wrong? Thanks

Comment: @yourfavoritedev can you tell me your solution plz? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly the second example. Why to declare function in every component.? You could do this if you would like to pass argument from child component to parent component. If you only want to pass function to D component from A just pass it down.

Comment: @DominikTargosz Thanks. Now i understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to pass the function down to your child component you can do it this way

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    mode: "dashboard"
  };

  changeMode = () => {
    this.setState({ mode: "mode" });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.mode);
    return <Second mode={this.changeMode} />;
  }
}

class Second extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Third mode={this.props.mode} />;
  }
}

class Third extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Fourth mode={this.props.mode} />;
  }
}

class Fourth extends Component {
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.props.mode}>mode</button>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

You could use the second option if you would need to pass argument to parent component